# Pointers between OpenCL buffers

Tags: pointers, memory, opencl

Consider the following. In a context there exist two buffers allocated in device memory, buffer `A` and buffer `B`. One buffer contains a pointer to something in another buffer. Assuming the host will propery keep the buffers alive between kernel invocations, is it safe to have this setup? Particularly is it guaranted that the implementation will not move buffers around thus invalidating the pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems not, atleast if the context has more than one device.
Сlause `5.4.4 Migrating Memory Objects` of the specification among other things states:

> Typically, memory objects are implicitly migrated to a device for
>   which enqueued commands, using the memory object, are targeted.

And there seems to be no way to prohibit this migration, and no information on what happens if there is only one device in a context.

Alas it appears that the only way to keep addressing consistent is to allocate one huge buffer and do manual memory-management of it's contents storing all addresses as offsets from the beginning of the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL 1.2 does not support pointers to pointers in buffers, but it seems that OpenCL 2.0 will allow this. See the slide titled "SVM: Shared Virtual Memory" in [this presentation](http://indico.cern.ch/getFile.py/access?resId=0&materialId=slides&confId=140118).

Comment: It has nothing to do with pointers to pointers, even pointer in a buffer that points to some data in the same buffer will be invalidated if buffer is relocated.

Comment: What i meant was pointers to (pointers in buffers) regardless where they are located

Comment: There is no guarantee and you should avoid doing it. Instead, keep offsets instead of pointers. Then if the buffers move, they will still be valid. y= bufferB[bufferA[x]]